# 404 not found with Angular material moment adapter

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-moment

I have installed angular/material and angular/material-moment-adapter from npm, I have also installed moment.js. When I run the app, I get the following error:

zone.js:1050 GET https://localhost:44399/something/@angular/material-moment-adapter 404.

When I check my node_modules, the package is there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deleting your *node_modules* folder and running an *npm install*? Sometimes that clears things up for me.